# integrate ant junit generated test-results in gradle html report

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my gradle build script, I added doLast method to test task to run ant.junit task to execute tests from few jar files.

```
    test <<  {
      //run ant junit task with reports stored in $buildDir/test-results

      //after ant junit completion and "test" task completion, 
      //how can I get the gradle generated html report include the above test-results?    
    }
```

How do I enhance this task to get the gradle html report benefit? I see that ant junit test xml reports are properly getting created in $buildDir/test-results along with other "gradle test" created xmls. However $buildDir/reports/tests" contains only. I was hoping that gradle will pick up the ant junit created test result xml files as well and include in its html report. But this is not happening. How can I get this behaviour?

I tried to create another task of type TestReport. But it also did not help.

```
 task runTestsFromJar( type: TestReport ) {
        destinationDir=file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
        reportOn tasks.test, files("$buildDir/test-results/binary/test")
 }
```

I am working with gradle 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response from [gradle forum post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/integrate_ant_junit_generated_test_results_in_gradle_test_html_report), it seems generate gradle styled test html report is not available out-of-the box with gradle. Gradle TestReport task seems to be dependent on the binary output files generated by "test" task. These are not generated when the tests are run using ant.JUnitTask from gradle. 
I resorted to "ant JUnitReport task" finally to generate at least a meaningful consolidated report.

```
test <<  {
  //run ant junit task with reports stored in $buildDir/test-results

  //after ant junit completion  
   ant.junitReport( toDir: "$buildDir/reports") {
            fileset ( dir:"$buildDir/test-results" )
            report ( format:"frames", todir:"$buildDir/reports" )
   }
}
```

This gives a basic html report. One can customize as needed using XSLT.

Comment: You need to add the task definition for junitreport:
`ant.taskdef(name: 'junitreport', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator', classpath: configurations.[configuration-containing ant-junit.jar].asPath
    )`

Comment: See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39180709

Comment: here's that gradle forum link. the link above is dead. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/integrate-ant-junit-generated-test-results-in-gradle-test-html-report/3843

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating another [task of type Test](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.8/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) to replace your doAfter closure.

```
task antTests(type: Test){
  //configuration here
}
```

I believe at that point you can use the TestReport task in a similar manner as your previous attempt

```
task runTestsFromJar( type: TestReport ) {
    destinationDir=file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn test, antTests
}
```

My attempts to generate a report based on a directory of existing xml result files, and on the `binary` subfolder were unsuccessful as well

Comment: no luck. It still does not generate the report. I tried with gradle latest release version too.

Comment: Have you verified that the antTests task generates XML junit reports?

Comment: Also, does the generated test output from your previous implementation contain a results.bin file in $buildDir/test-results/binary/test for the task to report on?

Comment: Yes. I verified that xmls are present. Apparently this seems to be not feasible as per the response mentioned in http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/integrate_ant_junit_generated_test_results_in_gradle_test_html_report

Comment: Please review my [project in GitHub](https://github.com/tankertux/aggregate-ant-test-results).  I don't think it is the XML files that the TestReport task utilizes, rather the *.bin files in the nested 'binary' folder. I was not able to get the reports working without the *.bin files in that directory. Granted, the static test results that I am reporting on in src/rawResults are generated from another Gradle project, not Ant.

Comment: The answer to your linked forum response is basically the same as my original answer. Please consider accepting my answer if you feel that your current approach isn't practical.

Comment: I am afraid, I was looking for a solution using ant approach. I upvoted your answer but this is not the answer which addresses my query.