# Gradle Merge Junit Report

Tags: gradle, junit

Is there a way in gradle that the junit xml report can be merged into a single test report file.

When we executed our IntegrationTestSuite.java with cp-suite in ant there is a single junit report. On gradle multiple junit reports are created.

`IntegrationTestSuite.java`

```java
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(IntegrationTests.class)
@Categories.ExcludeCategory(DebugJenkinsTests.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(AllTestSuite.class)
public class IntegrationTestSuite { /* nop */
}
```

Snipped from `build.xml`

```xml
<junit>
   <formatter type="xml" />
      <batchtest todir="${testreport.dir}">
          <fileset dir="${test-src.dir}">
              <include name="**/IntegrationTestSuite.java" />
          </fileset>
       </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Snipped from `build.gradle`

```groovy
task integrationTestSandro(type: Test) {
    reports.html.enabled = false
    include '**/IntegrationTestSuite*'
    reports.junitXml.destination = "$buildDir/test-results/integration"
    maxHeapSize = testTaskMaxHeapSize
    jvmArgs testTaskJVMArgs
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the Ant task [JUnitReport](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) to achieve your goal. Something like the following should work:

```groovy
configurations {
    antJUnit
}

dependencies {
    antJUnit 'org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.7'
}

task mergeJUnitReports {
    ext {
        resultsDir = file("$buildDir/allreports")
        targetDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/merged")
    }

    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'junitreport',
                    classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator',
                    classpath: configurations.antJUnit.asPath)

        ant.junitreport(todir: resultsDir) {
            fileset(dir: resultsDir, includes: 'TEST-*.xml')
            report(todir: targetDir, format: 'frames')
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you will have to declare a repository to allow Gradle to resolve the `ant-junit` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add onto Benjamin's answer, since I had to make some changes to get it to work. Here's what my file ended up looking like.

```groovy
configurations {
    antJUnit
}

dependencies {
    antJUnit 'org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.7'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    // Disable the test report for the individual test task
    test {
        reports.html.enabled = false
        reports.junitXml.enabled = true
    }
}
// Compile all the test results into a single one.
task testReport { 
    ant.taskdef(name: 'junitreport', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator', classpath: configurations.antJUnit.asPath)
    dependsOn subprojects*.test 
    doFirst { 
        mkdir "$buildDir/test-results"
        ant.junitreport(todir: "$buildDir/test-results") { 
            subprojects.each { 
                if (it.testResultsDir.exists()) {
                    fileset(dir: it.testResultsDir) 
                }
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps someone who comes across this issue.