# Is there a way to make Gradle test results go to one xml file?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, ant, junit5

Gradle XML test results are currently being output into separate files based on the class name. Is there a way to make the XML test results all go to one file for all the classes? The Gradle version I am using is 5.5.1.

I have combed through the Gradle website and have not found anything related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Ant Task JUnitReport grabbed from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39180709/8583692):

```
configurations {
    antJUnit
}

dependencies {
    antJUnit 'org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.7'
}

task mergeJUnitReports {
    ext {
        resultsDir = file("$buildDir/allreports")
        targetDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/merged")
    }

    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(
            name: 'junitreport',
            classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator',
            classpath: configurations.antJUnit.asPath
        )

        ant.junitreport(todir: resultsDir) {
            fileset(dir: resultsDir, includes: 'TEST-*.xml')
            report(todir: targetDir, format: 'frames')
        }
    }
}
```