# Gradle: using the TestReport task with different XML file

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, reporting

I have a gradle task that produces a test report as XML file.

```
build
└── test-results
    ├── test                     // result of the regular unit tests
    │   ├── TEST-SomeTest.xml
    │   └── binary
    │       ├── output.bin
    │       ├── output.bin.idx
    │       └── results.bin
    └── testCustom               // result of my custom task 
        └── TEST-my-lib-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.xml
```

I would like to use the standard `TestReport` feature of gradle ([test reporting](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_reporting)) to generate an HTML report for my XML result.

```
def testCustom = tasks.register('testCustom') {
    // This is producing the XML test result. 
}

tasks.register('testCustomReport', TestReport) {
    dependsOn testCustom
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/testCustom")
    testResultDirs.from(file("$buildDir/test-results/testCustom/"))
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn testCustom, testCustomReport
}
```

With this I get an empty `reports/tests/testCustom` folder:

```
build
└── reports
    └── tests
        ├── test
        │   ├── classes
        │   │   └── ... .html
        │   ├── css
        │   │   ├── base-style.css
        │   │   └── style.css
        │   ├── index.html
        │   ├── js
        │   │   └── report.js
        │   └── packages
        │       └── ... .html
        └── testCustom
```

I guess my custom `TestReport` task is wrongly configured.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason and a solution in others StackOverflow posts:

> Gradle TestReport task seems to be dependent on the binary output files generated by "test" task

From [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536390)

So there is no way it will work with my XML created by my `customTest` task.

The alternative is to use the [ant-junit library to create the report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39180709), and it works.